# (Pandas) Index header and variable headers are not in the same row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
pred = pd.DataFrame( pred, index = test.device_id ) 
pred.columns = colnames
```

I'd like the header of each column to be in the same row. But they are not as seen in the image below. How can I correct this?

[image]

Comment: `pred.reset_index()`.

Comment: That's a display choice so it is clear that the device_id is the name of the row index. You can set `pred.index.name = None` if you don't want it.

Comment: I still want the index header, but just in the same row as the rest of the headers. Is there a fix for that?